# Issue with javascript on a visualforce page - document.querySelector returns null

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I have a VF page that call a flow when a custom button is clicked (maybe not a best practice but I'm working on this project, and I not have time to rework all this process...). The problem is that when we are in a community, this button should be hide or disabled.

So for now in the VF page I just filter if we are in a community using `Site.getSiteId()` and I can detect if I am in a community or not, with something like this :

```
<apex:pageBlockSection rendered="{!isInCommunity != true}">
    <flow:interview name="AssignCases"
    finishLocation="{!IF($User.UITheme == 'Theme4d' || $User.UITheme == 'Theme4t','/one/one.app#/sObject/Case/home','/500')}">
    <apex:param name="socvCasecoll" value="{!Selected}"/>
    <apex:param name="vUid" value="{!$User.Id}"/>
    </flow:interview>

</apex:pageBlockSection>

<apex:pageBlockSection rendered="{!isInCommunity == true}">

</apex:pageBlockSection>
```

So I'm not sure if I need touse the second `apex:pageBlockSection`, but i try to put some javascript at the bottom of my page to retrieve the button (and try to hide it later):

```
var isInCommunity ={!isInCommunity};
    console.log('isInCommunity : ' + isInCommunity);
    if(isInCommunity == true){
        console.log('passe dans isInCommunity == true');
        var bouton = document.querySelector('.forceActionLink');
        console.log(bouton);
    }
```

but the problem is that I got `null` in the log, so I can't hide it...

**** EDIT ****

Here is the DOM with the button : 
[image]

I also try to get the element by using `document.querySelector('a[title="M\'affecter cette demande"]')` to isolate the `a` tag, but it also returns null.

Comment: Your included markup does not make any reference to `forceActionLink`, let alone in a class. What leads you to believe this selector is the right one?

Comment: Thats because the buton with this markup isn't in the VF, it is a custom button that is on the list of the case, and this custom button call the VF page. I got the markup when inspecting the page, since I can't add any class or id to the button...

Comment: Are you sure it's in the same window? Not in an iframe or anything?

Comment: I don't see any ifram or anything... but as I said in the question, I don't know if it was very clear, the button isn't in the VF page where I call the javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can not access Apex variable in JavaScript like this.

**var isInCommunity ={!isInCommunity};**

Correct way to access apex variable in Javascript :

**var isInCommunity = '{!isInCommunity}';**

Comment: even if the apex variable is a boolean ? Because if I use the simple quote, then I did not pass into the if, event if the var isInCommunity is true...

Comment: ohh.. Mak sure you call query selector after DOM has loaded.

Comment: Well I try to call first `window.onload` but same problem...

Comment: can you show me DOM code of forceActionLink ?

Comment: I editedt mu question with a copy of the dom for the button